# Reiniciar tiempo con jquery de un sitio web

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
 $(".intime2").delay(2000).fadeIn(0);

setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime40').fadeOut(0);
}, 40000);
```

Necesito poder reiniciar el tiempo al pasar por encima de un div en un jquery para que las funciones time-delay se reinicien... No quiero hacer un loop ni nada parecido, solo cuando el puntero pasa sobre el div que se reinicie el tiempo.

Comment: ¿Te refieres a reiniciar la cola tras algún `delay()`?¿O algo que estaba con un `setTimeout()` o `setInterval()`?

Comment: Actualicé la pregunta para aclarar con los 2 casos de tiempo que manejo @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: Gracias. Básicamente son los dos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para reiniciar un `setTimeout` o `setInterval` lo que tienes que hacer es añadir un manejador (*handler* en inglés) donde puedas limpiar la función retrasada. Para ello utilizas las funciones [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearTimeout) y [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/clearInterval) respectivamente.

En tu caso:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime40').fadeOut(0);
}, 40000);
```

deberías asignar el intervalo a un manejador que puede limpiarse después:

```
miIntervalo = setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime40').fadeOut(0);
}, 40000);
```

Entonces cuando pases por encima del `div`, primero limpias el intervalo y después lo vuelves a definir:

```
// limpiar intervalo
clearInterval(miIntervalo);

// redefinir intervalo
miIntervalo = setInterval(function() {
    $('.outtime40').fadeOut(0);
}, 40000);
```

---

En el caso de `delay()` en jQuery, lo que tienes que hacer es usar [`stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) y de nuevo redefinir lo que quieras hacer. Así, cuando pases por encima del `div` el código se vería como algo así:

```
$(".intime2").stop(true, true).delay(2000).fadeIn(0);
```

El primer parámetro indica si quieres que se borre la cola de animaciones, y el segundo indica si quieres que se salte al final.

---

Ahora pon las dos cosas juntas, suponiendo que tu `div` tiene el id "miDiv":

```
$("#miDiv").on("mouseenter", function() {

    // limpiar intervalo 
    clearInterval(miIntervalo);

    // redefinir intervalo
    miIntervalo = setInterval(function() {
        $('.outtime40').fadeOut(0);
    }, 40000);

    $(".intime2").stop(true, true).delay(2000).fadeIn(0);
});
```

Comment: Increible ! Es perfecto muchas gracias.